# How to GROUP ARRAY in right way

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to receive `participant_name` of winner per each `race_name` from the following table

```sql
WITH race AS (    
  SELECT 'A' AS race_name, [4, 1, 3] as participant_id, [25.3, 29.4, 24.1] as timing  UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'B', [2, 1, 4, 6], [16.3, 14.2, 17.4, 18.3] UNION ALL    
  SELECT 'C', [7, 5, 4, 2], [19.5, 21.4, 16.4, 15.6]     
),

participant AS (    
  SELECT 1 as participant_id, 12 as participant_age, "Julie" as participant_name UNION ALL    
  SELECT 2, 11, "Max" UNION ALL    
  SELECT 3, 12, "John" UNION ALL    
  SELECT 4, 11, "Matt" UNION ALL    
  SELECT 5, 13, "Diana" UNION ALL    
  SELECT 6, 12, "Peter" UNION ALL    
  SELECT 7, 11, "Ben"     
)

SELECT race_name, 
  (SELECT participant_name 
    FROM participant CROSS JOIN UNNEST(timing) AS duration 
    ORDER BY duration ASC 
    LIMIT 1
  )
FROM race
```

I receive `participant_name` of the participant with the lowest timing, but not per each `race_name`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT race_name, 
  (SELECT participant_name
    FROM UNNEST(participant_id) AS participant_id WITH OFFSET 
    JOIN UNNEST(timing) AS duration WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
    LEFT JOIN participant USING(participant_id)
    ORDER BY duration ASC 
    LIMIT 1
  ) participant_name 
FROM race
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row race_name   participant_name     
1   A           John     
2   B           Julie    
3   C           Max
```